# Store and retrieve images into sdcard

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I have a set of image urls. I download it to bitmap. Now I want to store these images into sdcard/project folder. If I don't have such a file, I have to create it. What I have done right now is:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
OutputStream fOut = null;
File file = new File(path, imageName);
if(!file.exists()) {
    file.mkdir();
    try {
        fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOut);
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
        MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), "file://"
            + file.getAbsolutePath(), file.getName(), file.getName());

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But I am not getting images inserted into sdcard. What is wrong in my code? Please reply. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the below code:

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    String fileName = edtNameImage.getText().toString().trim();//this can be changed
    if (fileName.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Fields cannot be left blank",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator + fileName);
    // write the bytes in file
    FileOutputStream fo;
    try {
        file.createNewFile();
        fo = new FileOutputStream(file);//snapshot image is the image to be stored.

        if (snapShotImage!=null)
        {
            snapShotImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        }else{
            return false;
        }
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        // ChartConstants.IMAGE_STORAGE++;
        fo.flush();
        fo.close();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    return true;
```

You can also check for duplicacy in names with some additional code lines. 
Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you made sure that the appropriate permissions for writing to/reading from an external storage device have been set in your Manifest.xml file?
2. Also, does the code exit with any of the exceptions above? Print more illustrative messages than the stacktrace. Something like so:

   try {
     
   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
     Log.v(this.toString(), "Exception caught in  block");
   }

or something on these lines..

HTH
Sriram

Answer (score 0):

Problems with your code:
1) You are creating a directory with the filename. Instead try mkdir() with only the 'path'
2) Pass only 'file.getAbsolutePath()' without the "file://" to insertImage() function
3) There is an alternate api to [insertImage](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media.html#insertImage%28android.content.ContentResolver,%20android.graphics.Bitmap,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) for which you need not create one more file locally. Pass the bitmap directly to that.

Hope this helps.